# Android AppStateManager :: Internal data leak within a DataBuffer object detected

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am using AppState to store my current Android application data. When I call the
`load` method and set a callback listener i see the following in my logcat output.

> Internal data leak within a DataBuffer object detected!  Be sure to
>   explicitly call close() on all DataBuffer extending objects when you
>   are done with them.
>   (com.google.android.gms.appstate.AppStateBuffer@45454128)

This is my method call (I am not explicitly opening any buffers)

```
AppStateManager
    .load(getApiClient(), APP_STATE_STATE_KEY)
    .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<AppStateManager.StateResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(final StateResult stateResult) {
        }
    });
```

e.g. The `onResult()` method is empty, so why do i see this logcat entry?
What buffer do i need close?

Comment: does no one know how to stop these "Internal data leak" messages from appearing? how can i close a DataBuffer i havent explicitly opened?

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @swalkner, thanks for asking, No I never found a solution, I am guessing its a "Feature" of using the android code base, hopefully the android dev team will address it one day and it will finally get resolved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a buffer what you need to close, but the connection instead. Even though your onResult method is empty it is the result of a callback, which means a connection was established.

I saw the same logcat output with Google Maps Api when I ommited

```
GoogleApiClient.disconnect()
```

at the end of the activity/fragment lifecycle